# How to determine maximum amount of data that can be handled by 1 run of MR2 job?

Tags: java, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I am running a YARN job on CDH 5.3 cluster. I have default configurations.

```
No of nodes=3
yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores=8
yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb=10GB
mapreduce.[map/reduce].cpu.vcores=1
mapreduce.[map/reduce].memory.mb=1GB
mapreduce.[map | reduce].java.opts.max.heap=756MB
```

While doing a run on 4.5GB csv data spread over 11 files ,I get following error:

```
2015-10-12 05:21:04,507 FATAL [IPC Server handler 18 on 50388] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Task: attempt_1444634391081_0005_r_000000_0 - exited : org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle$ShuffleError: error in shuffle in fetcher#9
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle.run(Shuffle.java:134)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:376)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1642)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.BoundedByteArrayOutputStream.<init>(BoundedByteArrayOutputStream.java:56)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.BoundedByteArrayOutputStream.<init>(BoundedByteArrayOutputStream.java:46)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.InMemoryMapOutput.<init>(InMemoryMapOutput.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.MergeManagerImpl.unconditionalReserve(MergeManagerImpl.java:303)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.MergeManagerImpl.reserve(MergeManagerImpl.java:293)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Fetcher.copyMapOutput(Fetcher.java:511)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Fetcher.copyFromHost(Fetcher.java:329)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Fetcher.run(Fetcher.java:193)
```

Then I tuned mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=1GB to mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=3GB and job runned fine.

So how to decide on how much data maximum can be handled by 1 reducer assuming that all the input to mapper have to be processed by 1 reducer only?

Answer (score 0):

Generally there is no limitation on the data that can be processed by a single reducer. The memory allocation can slow down the process but must not restrict or fail to process the data. I believe after allocating minimum memory to reducer the data processing should not be an issue. Can u pls share some code snippet to check for any memory leak issues.
We used to process 6+Gb of file in a single reducer withou any issues. I believe you might be having memory leak issues.